# Require Not Working During Mocha Test On Extended Javscript Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am attempting to npm mocha test a class that extends another class in another js file.

The problem I'm running into is that the code works fine when running in production but when running `npm test` ClassTwo cannot see class one regardless that I'm requiring it or not. If I add the definition for class one in the file for class two then it works fine.

I can't put a require in ClassTwo.js because it causes the browser code to explode since require isn't a concept there.

ClassOne.js

```
class ClassOne{

}

if(typeof module !== 'undefined'){
    module.exports = ClassOne;
}
```

ClassTwo.js

```
class ClassTwo extends ClassOne{

}

if(typeof module !== 'undefined'){
    module.exports = ClassTwo;
}
```

test.js

```
const ClassOne = require('../js/ClassOne.js');
const ClassTwo = require('../js/ClassTwo.js');

... unit tests ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to create a global variable in the test.js file that was named the same as my extended class and then hydrate it with the require command.

test.js

```
const { global } = require("@sinonjs/commons");

global.ClassOne = require('../js/ClassOne.js');

const ClassTwo = require('../js/ClassTwo.js');
```